# libGDX Ordering Tasks

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a game in libGDX. I am having a problem with trying to get the AI to do tasks in order. I originally used libGDX Timers to schedule the tasks, but this does not really suit what I am trying to accomplish.

The game is a strategy turn based game so the order in which the tasks are completed is important.

Here is how I am currently doing it

```
float teamSizeDelay = team.getUnits().size() * gameSpeed;
float eventDelay = gameSpeed * 2;

// Move Units
if (team.getUnits().size() > 0 && enemyTeam.getHqHealth() > 0) {
    unitIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < team.getUnits().size(); i++) {
        Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                selectUnit(unitIndex);
                unitIndex++;
            }
        }, i * gameSpeed);
    }
}

int availableFactories = getAvailableFactories();

// Spawn Units
Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (enemyTeam.getHqHealth() > 0)
            spawnUnits();
    }
}, teamSizeDelay + eventDelay * 2);

float spawnDelay = availableFactories * gameSpeed;

// End Turn
if (enemyTeam.getHqHealth() > 0) {
    Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            endTurn();
        }
    }, (teamSizeDelay) + (eventDelay * 3) + (spawnDelay));
}
```

As you can see using timers can be messy, especially with the timings

So if anyone knows a better way to do this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the game is turn based, why do you have the time-related code (i.e. `i * gameSpeed` and `teamSizeDelay + eventDelay * 2`)? Why not make these actions occur instantaneously?

Comment: Because I want the player to be able to see what moves the computer made, instead of the turn just happening in an instant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to execute a bunch of tasks serially, but with time delays in between tasks. One way to do this in libGDX would be to extend Scene2D's [`Action` class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Action.html) and create different actions for your AI, sequence them with the [`SequenceAction` class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.html), and space them using the [`DelayAction` class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/DelayAction.html).

Setting up your AI's actions would look something like this:

```
action = new SequenceAction();
for(Unit u : units) {
  action.addAction(new MoveUnitAction( ... ));
  action.addAction(Actions.delay( gameSpeed ));
}
action.addAction(new SpawnUnitsAction( ... ));
action.addAction(Actions.delay( gameSpeed ));
action.addAction(new EndTurnAction( ... ));
```

Then you run the action until it completes like so:

```
public void render(float delta) { // Or whatever your per-frame method is called.
  if(action.act(delta)) {
    // This line runs when the AI's tasks are complete.
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use Scene2D, you could of course implement your own solution, but it would work essentially the same way.

Comment: If I use scene2D will I have to use a stage? Or can I just have runnable code that I add to the action queue? I've almost finished the game without scene2D and I'd rather not have to redo everything to be compatible with it

Comment: I believe you could do it without a Stage so long as you call `Action#act()` yourself somewhere in your game loop.

Comment: I created my own sort of action handler to handle custom actions for the AI without the use of scene2D, thanks for the suggestion!